# Python command line input doesn't delete japanese characters when pressing the erase key

Tags: python, text, encoding, command-line

I have a command line python application which reads japanese characters from the command line input. The problem is that the 'erase' key doesn't work very well, let me explain:

What happens is that, when I try to delete  a kanji, the character seems to not be deleted: the character is actually deleted (I know this because I have debugged it) but it still appears in the command line. E.g., suppose I have the following characters:

```
四つください。
```

Now, if I press the erase key 3 times I get:

```
四つくださ
```

As you can see, only two characters have been deleted (the `。` and the `い`). However, if I press enter, the script interprets correctly that the only remaining characters are `四つくだ`. So in other words, the 3 characters are actually deleted, but the `さ` is still visible in the terminal.

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem gets fixed doing the following:

```
# In the terminal:
pip install readline


# In the script
import readline
```

Don't know what that fixes the problem, but it does.

Comment: `readline` just uses terminal data, and so it can do the right things. Usually terminal may just know about char (think about bytes), and most of real characters requires more then one single byte